# How do I reference/insert an href variable in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var url = settings.basePath +"localhost"

if(queues.length>0) {
  tempalteMsg += "Queues"+ "<a href='url>'</a>"
}
```

how do I refer to the url var in that a tag string?

Comment: Use es6 template string ```tempalteMsg += `Queues <a href="${url}">'</a>` ```

Comment: using concatenation is another way: `"Queues<a href='" +url+ "'>Link</a>"`

Comment: @NickParsons thanks so much to that works as well, this willl be so handy for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var url = settings.basePath +"localhost"

if(queues.length>0) {
  tempalteMsg += "Queues"+ "<a href='${url}'></a>"
}
```

Comment: Consider removing `"+ "` if you're using template strings?

Comment: Consider using Template strings, if you want the string interpolation to work: `tempalteMsg += \`Queues <a href="${url}"></a>\``